# Scrape HTML off AppBuilder page

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, ecmascript-6

I found this website with some interesting data I wish to analyze. But the page is really slow and build around .docx files. But it has a preview of each document in HTML

http://www.produktresume.dk/AppBuilder/search?page=0

My current idea for a strategy is:

1. Wait for the page to load (haven't tried this before)
2. Dig into the `div class="widget_inside"`
3. Grab all the `href` in `<a class="preview_link"`
4. Iterate over all the collected links and parse the HTML into some `.json`/`.csv` for later analysis

I'm pretty new when it comes to scraping, and had previously some luck with `BeautifulSoup` in Python - with a page that don't have a loading. But I have been using nodejs lately, so would prefer to be able to do it in JS with some npm package.

Anybody who can help me out finding the right tools for the job and some pointers/comments on the best strategy?

---

## Bonus info

By decoding one of the filter links to the left this comes up:

`http://www.produktresume.dk/AppBuilder/search?expand_all=true&page=0&refinements_token={}&selected_tokens[]={"s":[{"id":"folder-refinement","xPath":"$folders","separator":"\u003e","logic":"OR","s":[{"n":"Human","k":"Human"}]}]}`

Don't know if that would be of any use?

Comment: There seems to be 7580 results, do you want all of those links?

Comment: @G_M yes please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***so would prefer to be able to do it in JS with some npm package***

Although I used Python, this answer shows a very simple and synchronous (slow!) way of grabbing all of those preview links. It took about 1 hour and 15 minutes to go through all 757 pages.

I wasn't sure how exactly you wanted to save the information in each of those preview links so I left that part to you. It would also be trivial to modify this script to simply download all of those `.docx` files instead of just grabbing the preview links.

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    WebDriverException
)

base_url = 'http://www.produktresume.dk'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('{}/AppBuilder/search'.format(base_url))

result = []
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    preview_links = [base_url + link['href']
                     for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='preview_link')]
    result.extend(preview_links)

    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Næste')
        element.click()
    except (NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException):
        break

driver.quit()

with open('preview_links.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(result, f, indent=2)
```

---

#### `preview_links.json`

- https://bpaste.net/show/b597d6910f18

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!!!